# Can tag wikis disappear?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I'm certain I created a tag wiki for [jehovahs-witnesses](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jehovahs-witnesses), but there isn't one now. Is my memory deceiving me, or did someone delete it? And, if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no they will not just disappear. In fact they are versioned so that you can see the [history of who changed what](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/3349/revisions). Obviously I don't see any changes from you in there.

Perhaps you changed a similar related tag wiki that later got removed or merged into this one or some other action?

Comment: Possibly. I know there was at one time a `jehovah-witnesses` tag. Perhaps it was that one. Ah well, never mind. I'll do it again.